# Flex Device Model and Make information

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex4.6

Is it possible to detect the device model and make information from a flex 4.5 sdk application, like Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.0 or Apple iPad 4 etc.,

Thanks

Fayaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[flash.system.Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/system/Capabilities.html) is the only way of obtaining certain info about your device Capabilities: i.e. os - Operating System. However, I don't think that it fits your requirements.

Another possibility is using [ANE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html)s. They allows you to extend your applications with native code (Android, iOS, Win, OSX, etc). You have to implement your solution in native code and package it as an ANE (or be lucky and search the web looking for already existing ANE that does what you want).

More info: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am aware of ANE's. But, I was expecting to find some library in flex sdk which will give me that info.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

[Android Native Device Info.](https://github.com/funky-monkey/Android-Native-Device-Info)

> Android Native Device Info: Grab native device info like OS, Model,
>   Brand, SDK Version and CPU. These AS3 classes uses Adobe AIR for
>   Android to grab an Android system file named /system/build.prop, parse
>   it and store its values in an nice value object for you to use. This
>   parsed information is mainly used for analytics.